# How to create match in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

This my string.

```
eewer <br> <br/> <div> ss</div> <img src=".."> dffdfdf df df sdf
```

I need to delete all tags and br replaced to `\n`

Example:

Before

`eewer <br> <br/> <div> ss</div> <img src=".."> dffdfdf df df sdf`

After

`eewer \n \n ss dffdfdf df df sdf`

Comment: the continuation of the story http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191910/how-to-remove-img-except-src-regex , right?

Comment: Is this string inside another HTML element (like a `<div>`)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This is another

Comment: how about this string `<div>eewer <br> <br/> <div> ss</div>some text</div> <img src=".."> dffdfdf df df sdf` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest remove all tags and br replace to \n

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep `\n`:

```js
var str = 'eewer <br> <br/> <div> ss</div> <img src=".."> dffdfdf df df sdf';

console.log(str.replace(/(<br>|<br\/>)/g, '\\n').replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ''));
```

If you want to have break-lines instead of `\n`:

```js
var str = 'eewer <br> <br/> <div> ss</div> <img src=".."> dffdfdf df df sdf';

console.log(str.replace(/(<br>|<br\/>)/g, '\n').replace(/<[^>]*>/g, ''));
```

Comment: @Andiskiy Does it satisfy you?

Comment: Why `\\n` just  `\n`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir OP wants to keep it as '\n' not just break line. Check his question again.

Comment: I think OP is mistaken!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Okey then. I've made two code snippets, for both cases :P

Comment: @Kinduser \n - break-lines

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Andiskiy My pleasure.

Comment: can not do one the regular expressions?

Comment: @Andiskiy You mean without two `.replace()` functions?

Comment: Just a hint: Use the callback. `.replace(..., function(match, tag) {  ...  });` and check if the tag is br or not!

Comment: `/<([a-z]+)[^>]*>/g` to group the tagname!

Comment: @Andiskiy It would be easy to do without two `.replace()` functions if only you would change both cases into the same element, but the first case is `\n` and the second is `''`. It can be done (probably) with callback as ibrahim mentioned, but it will complicate your code and will be much more of code than it is now.

Comment: @Andiskiy I'm with KindUser. Two `replace` calls is better to keep things separated!

Comment: @Andiskiy Would you like to mark it as the best answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

First replace all BR tags by:

```
 /<br\s?\/?>/g
```

And remove others:

```
 /<.*?\n?.*?>/g
```

Or if your tags can be complicated and multilines (3 or more):

```
 /<(.*?\n?){0,}.*?>/g
 /<[^>]*>/g   //is faster as @Zze suggested
```

So:

```
 yourString.replace( /<br\s\/?>/g , '\n' ).replace( /<.*?\n?.*?>/g ,'') ;
```

Note: Replacing:

```
 <br> <br/> <br /> and <br >
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: can not do one the regular expressions?

Comment: We're replacing BR tags with \n while other tags replacing with ''. () captures existing texts.

Answer (score 1):

I split this up into 2 replace statements, however people whom are better than I at regex could possibly optimise this..

`/(<br[\/]*>)/g` captures your html line breaks.

`/<[^>]*>/g` captures all other html tags and their contents.

```js
var string = 'eewer <br> <br/> <div> ss</div> <img src=".."> dffdfdf df df sdf';

console.log(string);
var newString = string.replace(/(<br[\/]*>)/g, "\n");
newString = newString.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
console.log(newString);
```

If you're looking to improve your regex, http://regexr.com is an amazing site with many community examples / cheatsheets available to use freely.